# Finding a cauchy sequence that does not converge on M

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

We define the following infinity norm on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$l_\infty(\mathbb{R}) = \{ (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \,\mid\, x_i \in \mathbb{R}, \sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \left|x_i\right|<\infty \}$$

Now let $M \subset l_\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be the subspace consisting of all sequences $x =(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with finitely many nonzero terms.

Now the questions asks me to *Find a Cauchy sequence in M that does not converge in M.*

I do not know how to approach this problem. Otherwise I would have tried, I have problems thinking about how the norm is defined on R, and all the symbols confuse me. Could someone help me break this down, into something very elementary and basic? =)

Comment: What you quoted is not a norm, but the definition of  $l_{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, which is the space of bounded infinite sequences of real numbers.  The norm of any sequence is the greatest absolute value of any element of the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will denote your space of all bounded real sequences by $X$ and let $M \subset X$ be as in your post. Also, for the sake of simplicity later, let's denote the $i$-th term of the sequence $z$ by $z(i)$ (instead of the usual $z_i$). Since you specifically asked about the norm, it is given by
$$\|z\|_X = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |z(i)|$$

Let $x$ be the sequence defined by $x(n) = 1/n$ and let $x_m$ be the sequence defined by truncating the sequence $x$ after the first $m$ terms. That is, $x_m(n) = 1/n$ if $n \le m$ and $x_m(n) = 0$ otherwise.

Then we have that $x_m \in M$ for all $m$ and
$$\|x - x_m\|_X = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x(n) - x_m(n)| = 1/(m+1)$$

so that $\|x - x_m\|_X \to 0$ and hence $x_m \to x$ in $X$. So we have shown that $x_m$ is a convergent sequence in $X$. Therefore, it is also a Cauchy sequence. Moreover, the all the $x_m$ lie in $M$, but the limit $x$ is obviously not in $M$ (it is never $0$). Hence $x_m$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ which does not converge in $M$ (even though it converges in $X$).

In a sense, this is the only type of example you can come up with. Since $X$ is complete, a subset $M$ will be complete if it is closed which would mean, of course, that every Cauchy sequence in $M$ will converge in $M$. So you have to show that $M$ is not closed, which we did above by finding a convergent sequence of terms in $M$ whose limit is not in $M$.